# CoreData - PickerView updating a tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, uipickerview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Look this code:

**Models:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDetails: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var exerciseName: String
    @NSManaged var repsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var setsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var trainingDay: TrainingDay

}
```

and

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDay: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var day: String
    @NSManaged var dayIndex: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var trainingDetails: NSSet

}
```

and this function **here**:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let currentDay = daysArray[row]

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDetails")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "trainingDay.day == %@", currentDay)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exerciseName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        detailsArray = (moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDetails])!
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Now, as you can see, I have a pickerView which **should** update a tableView everytime I selected a different option inside it, but that's not happening. I know instead of **let currentDay = daysArray[row]** I should attribute a fetchedResultsController from CoreData to currentDay, then try to update the tableView.

My question is: Am I right to think this? How do I do it?

I'm new to Swift, I would love some examples on how to do it.

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE** -> Full code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        VDL()

        //sets stepper configs
        setsStepper.wraps = false
        setsStepper.autorepeat = true
        setsStepper.continuous = true
        setsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        setsStepper.minimumValue = 0
        setsStepper.maximumValue = 500
        setsStepper.value = 0

        //reps stepper configs
        repsStepper.wraps = false
        repsStepper.autorepeat = true
        repsStepper.continuous = true
        repsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        repsStepper.minimumValue = 0
        repsStepper.maximumValue = 500
        repsStepper.value = 0

        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    @IBOutlet var exerciseTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var daysPickerView: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var exerciseName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var setsStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var repsStepper: UIStepper!

    @IBOutlet var setsNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var repsNumber: UILabel!

    var daysArray = [TrainingDay]()
    var detailsArray = [TrainingDetails]()

    func VDL () {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDay")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dayIndex", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        daysArray = (moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDay])!
        if daysArray.count == 0 { // nothing there
            let dayEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
            let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
            for (index, name) in enumerate(days) {
                let newDay = TrainingDay(entity: dayEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
                newDay.day = name
                newDay.dayIndex = index
                daysArray.append(newDay)
                println("NAME: \(newDay.day) INDEX: \(newDay.dayIndex)")
            }
            var error: NSError?
            moc!.save(&error)
        }
    }


    func appendTrainingDetailsToArray () {
        let row = daysPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let currentDay = daysArray[row]

        let detailsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: detailsEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text
        trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.trainingDay = currentDay

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("CURRENT SETTING: \(trainingdetails.trainingDay)")
        }
    }

    func fetchTrainingDetails() -> NSFetchRequest {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDetails")
        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "trainingDay", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        return fetchRequest
    }

    @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        appendTrainingDetailsToArray()
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchTrainingDetails(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func setsStepperAction(sender: UIStepper) {
        println("\(Int(sender.value))")
        setsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    @IBAction func repsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
        println("\(Int(sender.value))")
        repsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("exerciseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let details = fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TrainingDetails
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(details.exerciseName)"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Sets: #\(details.setsNumber) Reps: #\(details.repsNumber)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        if self.fetchedResultsController == nil {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("section and row \(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row) ")
        if self.fetchedResultsController == nil {
            println("error when trying to delete object from managed object")

        } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

            switch editingStyle {
            case .Delete:
                moc?.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TrainingDetails)
                moc?.save(nil)
            case .Insert:
                break
            case .None:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    //PICKER VIEW DELEGATE AND DATASOURCE METHODS
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return daysArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
            let trainingDay = daysArray[row]
            return trainingDay.day
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let currentDay = daysArray[row]

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDetails")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "trainingDay.day == %@", currentDay)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exerciseName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        detailsArray = (moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDetails])!
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.exerciseTableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
    {
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            // Note that for Insert, we insert a row at the __newIndexPath__
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            // Note that for Delete, we delete the row at __indexPath__
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            // Note that for Update, we update the row at __indexPath__
            if let updateIndexPath = indexPath {
                let cell = self.exerciseTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath)
                let details = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath) as? TrainingDetails

                cell!.textLabel!.text = "\(details!.exerciseName)"
                cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Sets: #\(details!.setsNumber) Reps: #\(details!.repsNumber)"
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            // Note that for Move, we delete the row at __indexPath__
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([deleteIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }

            // Note that for Move, we insert a row at the __newIndexPath__
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.exerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        }    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        atIndex sectionIndex: Int,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
    {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            self.exerciseTableView.insertSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case .Delete:
            let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
            self.exerciseTableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        default:
            ""
        }
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        exerciseTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: There could be several reasons why the table view is not reloading. Can you post your table view related code too?  Also does the detailsArray contain some objects? or is it empty?

Comment: I updated the question with the full code! detailsArray should have TrainingDetails' objects.

Comment: I think you have already figured out what is the issue. You table actually loads its contents from the fetchRequestController, rather than the details array. That is why your table is not reloading details pertaining to a given day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to change the fetch request associated with the fetchedResultsController, and invoke performFetch() on it, and then reload the table view. In your

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  let currentDay = daysArray[row]
        //Update the fetch request related to the fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest that table view controller uses for its data
        let fetchRequest = fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "trainingDay.day == %@", currentDay)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exerciseName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        //Perform fetch afresh
        fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil);

        //Now reload the table view
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Refer: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW7)

> **Modifying the Fetch Request** 
>   You cannot simply change the fetch request
>   to modify the results. If you want to change the fetch request, you
>   must:
>
> If you are using a cache, delete it (using deleteCacheWithName:).
>
> Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch
>   request.
>
> Change the fetch request.
>
> Invoke performFetch:.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! With the code you provided, let's say I add all I want for "Monday" and now I select another row for "Tuesday", the table view reloads but gets empty, if I select "Monday" again, it remains empty, it does not reload the previous stuff I added.

Comment: I was thinking: what if we get the selected row in the picker view, extract it's name and assign it to a **var : string** and use it instead of **let currentDay = daysArray[row]** ? I guess the problem is there, currentDay is not receiving the proper day of CoreData because **daysArrow** is just a tool to order things properly in this table view, the stuff saved are not actually saved in that array. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: If getting the string from the picker view is the solution, could you teach me how to do it?

Comment: I managed to do it! I got the string from the pickerView and used to assign the correct day to currentDay, now whenever I select a different row in the picker view, it reloads in the proper way!